# sql server case problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table product having 3 columns 
maker holding values{'HCL','ACER',HP}
model_no   PK
type        {PC,Printer,laptop}
I want to produce result set in following columns maker,pc,printer,laptop
if a maker has prouct of the above category display yes in respective column
else No
The following code displays yes to all even if maker has no products
It is req to use while and break statements.Please help me

```
select maker,'PC'= 
 case type
when 'pc' then 'Yes' 
when 'printer' then 'Yes'
when 'Laptop' then 'Yes'
else 'No'
end, 
'Laptop'= 
case type
when 'pc' then 'Yes' 
when 'printer' then 'Yes'
when 'Laptop' then 'Yes'
else 'No'
end,'Printer'=
case type
when 'pc' then 'Yes'
when 'printer' then 'Yes'
when 'Laptop' then 'Yes'
else 'No'
end  from product where maker='ACER'
```

Comment: Is this homework? (if so, please use the homework tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
select maker,
 case when type IN ('PC','Workstation','Server') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS PC,
 case when type IN ('Laptop','Tablet','Something') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Laptop,
 case when type IN ('Printer','Plotter','Inkjet') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Printer

from product 
where maker='ACER'
```

I took the liberty of changing your logic around. Put whatever conditions that valid a 'Yes' in each IN statement, then add as many as you need/wish.

Comment: -1 Your code does not work. `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'`. I guess you cant use `IN` in a `case` statement like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, i had forgotten a "WHEN" between case and type, when you use CASE and a column name afterwards, it expects a WHEN 'value' - the code above should run fine, using IN is perfectly valid in a CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  maker,
  case [type] when 'pc'      then 'yes' else 'no' end as PC,
  case [type] when 'Laptop'  then 'yes' else 'no' end as Laptop,
  case [type] when 'Printer' then 'yes' else 'no' end as Printer
from product
where maker = 'ACER'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        select maker,
        case type when 'pc' then 'Yes'  when 'printer' then 'Yes' when 'Laptop' then 'Yes'      else 'No' end AS PC, 
case type when 'pc' then 'Yes'  when 'printer' then 'Yes' when 'Laptop' then 'Yes' else 'No' end AS Laptop,
case type when 'pc' then 'Yes' when 'printer' then 'Yes' when 'Laptop' then 'Yes' else 'No' end AS Printer 

from product where maker='ACER'
```